# Selection Sort in Scala

Tags: scala, sorting

I am new to Scala and was trying the Selection Sort algorithm. I managed to do a min sort but when I try to do the max sort I get a sorted array but in decreasing order. My code is:

```
def maxSort(a:Array[Double]):Unit = {
    for(i <- 0 until a.length-1){
            var min = i
                    for(j <- i + 1 until a.length){
                            if (a(j) < a(min)) min = j
            }
    val tmp = a(i)
    a(i) = a(min)
    a(min) = tmp
    }
}
```

I know that I have to append my result at the end of the array, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will sort the array using the maximum in increasing order:

```
def maxSort(a:Array[Double]):Unit = {
  for (i <- (0 until a.length).reverse) {
    var max = i
    for (j <- (0 until i).reverse) {
      if (a(j) > a(max)) max = j
    }
    val tmp = a(i)
    a(i) = a(max)
    a(max) = tmp
  }
}
```

The main issue here is iterating through the array in reverse order, more solutions are provided here:
[Scala downwards or decreasing for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617513/scala-downwards-or-decreasing-for-loop)

**Please note that Scala is praised for it's functional features and functional approach might be more interesting and "in the style of language". Here are some examples of Selection Sort:**

[Selection sort in functional Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672074/selection-sort-in-functional-scala)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Select Sort in functional style:

```
  def selectionSort(source: List[Int]) = {
    def select(source: List[Int], result: List[Int]) : List[Int] = source match {
      case h :: t => sort(t, Nil, result, h) 
      case Nil => result
    }
    @tailrec
    def sort(source: List[Int], r1: List[Int], r2: List[Int], m: Int) : List[Int] = source match {
      case h :: t => if( h > m) sort(t, h :: r1, r2, m) else  sort(t, m :: r1, r2, h)
      case Nil =>  select(r1, r2 :+ m)
    }
    select(source, Nil)
  }
```